# hook_form_submit isn't called

Tags: 7, forms

i've build a form but the callback isn't called (but it is initialized)...

My module name is : fritr_register_friterie
My form name is : fritr_register_friterie_form
My form validate name is : fritr_register_friterie_form_validate
My form submit is : fritr_register_friterie_form_submit

My form is composed by standards fields and a field_attach_form.
My submit button code is :

```
$form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#weight' => 100,
    );
```

I've made a dsm($form) in my validate function and i get this (You can see in the #submit my function is called... i've tried a dsm(form_get_errors()) at the end of my validate function and there is no error in my validate) :
[image]

I don't know what i can do :s For more help, here is my full code (without validate and submit content) :

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function fritr_register_friterie_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();

    // FRITERIE FORM
    $form['friterie_fields'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Informations friterie (Obligatoire)'),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#collapsible' => FALSE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#weight' => 1,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('clean-panel'),
        ),
    );

    if (!isset($form['#node'])) {
        global $language;
        $form['#node'] = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'friterie', 'language' => $language->language));
    }
    field_attach_form('node', $form['#node'], $form['friterie_fields'], $form_state);    

    $form['is_owner'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Etes-vous le propriétaire de cette friterie ?'),
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Oui'),
            0 => t('Non'),
        ),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 2,
    );

    // USER REGISTER FORM
    $form['owner'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Informations responsable (Obligatoire)'),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#collapsible' => FALSE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#weight' => 3,
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="is_owner"]' => array('value' => 1),
            ),
        ),
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('clean-panel'),
        ),
    );

    $form['owner']['email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Email'),
        '#size' => 32,
        '#description' => "Please enter your email.",
    );

    $form['owner']['password'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password_confirm',
        '#description' => t('Enter the same password in both fields'),
        '#size' => 32,
    );

    $form['owner']['firstname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Votre prénom'),        
    );

    $form['owner']['lastname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Votre nom'),
    );    

    $form['owner']['friterie_immat'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Immatriculation de l\'entreprise (SIRET ou TVA Intracommunautaire)'),        
    );

    $form['owner']['phone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Votre téléphone personnel'),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Enregistrer la friterie'),
        '#weight' => 100,
    );

    // CLASS
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_mode_paiement']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4';
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_conditions_pay']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'clear-display';
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_photo_pack']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'clear-display';
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_presentation']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'clear-display'; 
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_facebook']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'clear-display';

    // ALT OTHER ATTR
    unset($form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_photo_pack'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#title']);
//    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_proprietaire']['#access'] = FALSE;

    // WEIGHT
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_adresse']['#weight'] = 1;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_presentation']['#weight'] = 3;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_horaires']['#weight'] = 4;    
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_mode_paiement']['#weight'] = 6;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_conditions_pay']['#weight'] = 7;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_budget_moyen']['#weight'] = 8;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_manger_sur_place']['#weight'] = 9;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_photo_pack']['#weight'] = 11;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_facebook']['#weight'] = 13;
    $form['friterie_fields']['field_friterie_site_web']['#weight'] = 14;

    // CONTAINER
    $wrapper_ids = array(
        'field_friterie_nom',
        'field_friterie_tel',
    );
    build_container($form, $form_state, 'field_friterie_nom_tel', $wrapper_ids, 2, 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 no-padding');
    $wrapper_ids = array(
        'field_friterie_menu_frites',
        'field_friterie_menu_viande', 
        'field_friterie_menu_sandwich', 
        'field_friterie_menu_autre'
    );
    build_container($form, $form_state, 'field_friterie_menu', $wrapper_ids, 5, 'row', 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6');
    $wrapper_ids = array(
        'field_friterie_photo_principale',
        'field_friterie_photo_2',
    );
    build_container($form, $form_state, 'field_friterie_photo_free', $wrapper_ids, 10, 'row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 clear-display', 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4');
    $wrapper_ids = array(
        'field_friterie_photo_3',
        'field_friterie_photo_4',
        'field_friterie_photo_5',
        'field_friterie_photo_6',
        'field_friterie_photo_7',
        'field_friterie_photo_8',
    );
    build_container($form, $form_state, 'field_friterie_photo_pay', $wrapper_ids, 12, 'row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 clear-display', 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4');            


    dsm($form);
    return $form;
}

function build_container(&$form, &$form_state, $wrapper_key, $wrapper_ids, $weight, $class_container = '', $class_field_wrapper = '') {
    $form['friterie_fields'][$wrapper_key] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => $weight,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array(
                $class_container,                
            ),
        ),
    );
    foreach ($wrapper_ids as $wrapper_id) {        
        $form['friterie_fields'][$wrapper_key][$wrapper_id] = $form['friterie_fields'][$wrapper_id];
        $form['friterie_fields'][$wrapper_key][$wrapper_id]['#attributes']['class'][] = $class_field_wrapper;
        unset($form['friterie_fields'][$wrapper_id]);
    }
} 

/*
 * Implements hook_form_validate().
 */
function fritr_register_friterie_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    dsm('validate handler');
}

/*
 * Implements hook_form_submit().
 */
function fritr_register_friterie_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    dsm('submit handler');
}
```

Comment: you can look into `https://www.drupal.org/node/717740`. Its an example of drupal 7 basic form. Hope you will get to know where you are missing.

Comment: The only thing i see different from my code is the usage of hook_menu. But this hook is only used to create link in the menu. Does i need to add this ? $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_my_form_submit'; Because on my screen we see the #submit is set.

Comment: Can you post your validate code too?

Comment: My validate is big and complex because i check the validation of the SIRET and i can't give you the code sorry :/ but i can tell you that is not the validate with cause the problem because without it it does the same thing (not accès the submit handler)

Comment: Found the solution of my problem... The caches flushing aren't good with drupal... i flush all caches and this not take the new version of my code with the #submit initialization.